R Shiny to R Script with randomization function "Warning: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'"
Beginner R programmer here trying to create a randomization interface for my study.
I am using the "SRS" R package to randomize subjects based on prognostic factors using the minimization method for recruiting centre and severity of condition. The study has 9 centres, one condition (2 levels II/III) and the patients will be randomized to two groups ("Standard", "Treatment"). The script works fine. I am now trying to connect Shiny to the R script with function. However, I get the "Warning: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'".
I am using RStudio 2023.12.1 and ‘shiny’ version 1.8.1.1.
library(shiny)
library(SRS)

Severity <- c("II", "III")
Centre <- c("A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F","G","H","I")

expt <- ClinicalExperiment(number.of.factors = 2,
                       factor.names = c("Centre", "Severity"),
                       number.of.factor.levels = c(9, 2),
                       factor.level.names =
                         list(c(Centre),
                              c(Severity)),
                       number.of.treatments = 2,
                       treatment.names <- c("Standard", "Treatment"))
r.obj <- new("PocockSimonRandomizer", expt, as.integer(12345))
         
my_function <- function(num,Centre, Severity) {
reactive(randomize(r.obj,input$num, c(input$Centre,input$Severity)))
}


# The ui part 

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num", "Study ID", value = 1, min = 1, max = 200),
  actionButton("click", "Randomize"),
  selectInput("Severity", "What's the stage?",Severity),
  selectInput("Centre", "What's the centre?", Centre),
  textOutput("text")
  )

# Define server

server <- function(input, output) {
  result <- eventReactive(input$click, {
    my_function(input$num, input$Severity, input$Centre)
  })
  output$text<- renderText(result())

  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

I have tried debugging myself and using the internet as a resource, but couldn't find how to fix it.

Your function should have the arguments you specify in the function, not the specific inputs. You include the inputs when you call the function. Also, take reactive out of the function.
So change my_function to:
my_function <- function(num,Centre, Severity) {
randomize(r.obj, num, c(Centre,Severity))
}

Then you can call with inputs in your eventReactive.
You also have undefined functions, like ClinicalExperimentz and randomize. There may be other issues, too.
